# Read environment variables from web.config in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, web-config

Here my **web.config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE" value="some test webconfig variable value" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can I read `TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE` from my **web.config** in `Startup.cs`?

I tried `Configuration["TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE"]`, but this variable doesn't exist in configuration values list.

Comment: Are you running from visual studio?

Comment: @Sanket yes, does it matter?

Comment: Yuriy - check my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While running from Visual Studio, use launchSettings.json like this-

```
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE":"123"
      }
    },
    "SamplePractice": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE":"123"
      }
    }
  }
```

Since launchSettings.json is only limited to Visual Studio, In case of publish version use web.config like this-

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyAspNetCoreApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" >
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    <environmentVariable name="TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE" value="123" />
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

And this environment value will read across application using -

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE");
```

**NOTE!** that it only works in case of publish.

Comment: That's the problem -
 Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE") returns null.

Comment: Did you added TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE in launchSettings.json while running from Visual Studio?

Comment: No, do I need it? I thought that TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE in web.config would be enough.

Comment: While running from visual studio, env variable pick up from launchsetting.json. in case of publish, it is pick up from web.config.

Comment: Ah, that's explain everything, I'll try to publish it then!

Comment: Yes, you're right about picking up from web.config in case of publish.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure you just need to call:

For individual setting:
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE"‌​);`

For list of settings:
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().GetEnumerator();`

Because you are accessing EnvironmentVariables from config not AppSettings

Comment: No, it doesn't work, first variant returns null, second - returns all environment variables, but without TEST_WEBCONFIG_VARIABLE.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Let  me take a quick look into my project